# How to subtract month from YYYYMMDD hh mm date format in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, date, date-format, angular-moment

Please anyone share the code to subtract month from this format date(2020,7,24, 11,0). For example,current date with time is **(2020,7,24, 11,0)** and i get (2020,6,24, 11,0).can anybody help me how to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you have object date, it's simple:

```js
const d = new Date(2020,7,24, 11,0);

// Remember in Date months starts from 0
console.log(d);

// Substract 1 month
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);

// Log
console.log(d);
```

Or if you need, you can parse manually

```js
// Set raw
const rawDate = '2020,7,24, 11,0';
console.log(rawDate);

// Convert your date
const [year, month, day, hour, minute] = rawDate.split(',');

// Set date
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(year);
d.setMonth(month-1); // Month starts from 0
d.setDate(day);
d.setHours(hour);
d.setMinutes(minute);

console.log(d);

// Substract month
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);

// Log
console.log(d);

// If you need to convert back to your format
const rawDateModified = `${d.getFullYear()},${d.getMonth()+1},${d.getDate()}, ${d.getHours()},${d.getMinutes()}`;
console.log(rawDateModified);
```

Updated answer to show how you can pass string to Date object

```js
// You get ds Date param as string
let ds = "2020,2,28,3,44";

// To pass it in Date object, you must
// convert it to array by splitting string
ds = ds.split(',');

// Then pass array to Date object with
// spread operator
const d = new Date(...ds);

// Log
console.log(d);
```

Comment: i got Property 'setYear' does not exist on type 'Date'.  this error?

Comment: Yes, you right, I've updated answer. setYear is deprecated, use setFullYear

Comment: its woking...i have another question Like:Date format  -- '2018, 07, 01, 10, 0' i have to remove 0 from only month day not from HH and mm.i tried replace(/\b0/g, '')but its remove 0 from all section.can you tell me how to do?

Comment: You can pass this kind of strings (like 07) to Date object, it will work. But if you need to make your string with no 0 in month or date, simplest way is to split your line by comma: `let [year, month, date, hour, min] = '2018, 07, 01, 10, 0'.split(',');`, then replace what you want i.e: `month = month.replace(/0(\d)/, '$1');`. Then put everything back to line.

Comment: Yes it's working.can u tell me  how to create this type format date- new Date(2020,2,28,3,44)

Comment: I didn't get your question - what's wrong with `const d = new Date(2020,2,28,3,44);` ? It creates proper date object.

Comment: actually i received  this string "2020,2,28,3,44"  from backend side then at front end side i will convert ?

Comment: Oh, now I get you! Ok, first you need to split your string to array: `const ds = "2020,2,28,3,44".split(',');`, then pass this array to Date object like so: `const d = new Date(...ds);`. I'll update my answer for this

Comment: ok bro i will try it i also tried at my side check my below question and check its correct or not:                                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102192/event-is-not-show-in-the-time-block-after-change-date-in-syncfusion-scheduler-li/63129292?noredirect=1#comment111668563_63129292

Comment: i will try and i got Expected 0-7 arguments ,but got 0 error after Date(...ds);

Comment: What happened where are u

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript Date objects months are starting from 0 and going to 11 instead of regular 1 to 12 months that we are used to.
In order to format it in a better way, you can use plain Javascript.

```js
    let now = new Date();
console.log(now); //Sat Jul 25 2020 13:55:30 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

let normalValues =[now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth()+1,now.getDate(),now.getHours(),now.getMinutes()]; 

let formated = normalValues.join(",");
console.log(formated); //2020,7,25,13,55
```

```
//Explanation for current time 2020/7/25 14:05
now.getFullYear(); //returns 2020
now.getMonth(); //Returns 6, that is why we add one to it to make it 7
now.getDate(); //Returns 25 
now.getHours(); //Returns 14
now.getMinutes(); //Returns 5
```